# Rewrite value in .ini file via PHP

Tags: php, regex, ini

I got a problem when I decided to make a system to change a configuration of my web site. I tried to open a file and rewrite a value of param in my conf.ini

conf.ini example:

```
[order]
show_suspended_orders=0
```

I want to change the value of "show_suspended_orders" to 1

Here is my code:

```
$value = 1;
$file = fopen("./conf.ini","w");
preg_replace("/show_suspended_orders=\d+$/","show_suspended_orders=".$value,$file,1);
fclose($file);
```

The problem is that function preg_replace deletes all the file content. Any idea? Thanks for your help.

Comment: `$file` is a file handle, while `preg_replace` expects a string. Also: you may want to store such settings in a database, it's a lot easier and less error-prone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$value = 1;
$file = file_get_contents("./conf.ini");
$file = preg_replace("/show_suspended_orders=\d+$/","show_suspended_orders=".$value, $file, 1);
file_put_contents("./conf.ini", $file);
```

Comment: I tried to save a result of preg_replace in a variable and then pass this variable to file_put_content as second param and it wokred, Thanks a lot!